# How to reuse a method while it is still running?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have the following code:

```
CreateMultiLayerWakeupSteps()
{
    var wakeupStep = new AutodetectWakeupStep
    {
        //Creating the object...
    }

    //Later in the process I have this operation:

    wakeupStep.SuccessNextStep = UserInputs(wakeupStep);
}
```

The **UserInputs** method implementation looks something like this:

```
    private static AutodetectCommandStep UserInputs(AutodetectWakeupStep wakeupStep)
    {
        AutodetectCommandStep autodetectCommandStep
        {
            //Creating the object...
        }

        //Some more operations autodetectCommandStep here...

        return autodetectCommandStep;
    }
```

In the **UserInputs** method I would like to call the **CreateMultiLayerWakeupStep** method again in order to create a new step but the following exception is thrown: **StackOverflowException**.

Is there a solution to reuse the method while still running ? It is difficult to implement ? I am not familiar with threading asynchronization.

Best regards !

Comment: You need to learn recursion. You trying to cal function while this function executes.

Comment: What you are trying to do results in an infinite loop. Which is of course only theoretically infinite because it bumps into the memory barrier. Totally expected. So your logic / design must have a flaw somewhere.

Comment: @tym32167 From what I know, recursion is a method that calls itself, and this is not my case

Comment: imagine you wrote: `static void foo() {bar();} static void bar() {foo();}` you get an infinite loop, which uses a little bit of memory every time `foo` or `bar` is called.

Comment: @ChiritescuAdrian your method ```CreateMultiLayerWakeupSteps``` is calling itself using method ```UserInputs```

Comment: @tym32167 I missed this, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing about multithreading here. You are trying to make a recursion, but you don't specify when the recursion will end. Because of that you receive `StackOverflowException`.

So for example you should have a property in `AutodetectCommandStep.ExecuteAgain`

```
void CreateMultiLayerWakeupSteps()
{
    var wakeupStep = new AutodetectWakeupStep
    {
        //Creating the object...
    }

    //Later in the process I have this operation:

    wakeupStep.SuccessNextStep = UserInputs(wakeupStep);

    if(wakeupStep.SuccessNextStep.ExecuteAgain)
        CreateMultiLayerWakeupSteps();
}
```

You should decide when this `ExecuteAgain` will be false depending on your context so you will leave the method. If it is always true, it will throw same exception.

Also probably a good idea is to create the AutodetectWakeupStep object outside the `CreateMultiLayerWakeupSteps(AutodetectWakeupStep wakeUpStep)`. And your code will look like this.

```
void CreateMultiLayerWakeupSteps(AutodetectWakeupStep wakeUpStep)
{

      AutodetectWakeupStep step = UserInputs(wakeupStep);

      if(step.ExecuteAgain)
           CreateMultiLayerWakeupSteps(step);
}
```